# How to fix a ~10006 error in applescript when duplicating a file to another folder?

Tags: applescript

When trying to duplicate files to another folder, the script throws a ~10006 error. This only occurs on some Mac mini computers and works fine on others. I have no idea why it is working on some computers but not on others.

This is the error shown:
Can't set "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Documents:" to  <> "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Downloads:new test:portal resources" of application "Finder". (~10006)

```
tell application "Finder"
set folderToBeMoved to (container of (path to me) as text) & 
"portal_resources"
set destinationFolder to path to documents folder as text
set moveFolder to duplicate folder folderToBeMoved to destinationFolder     with replacing
end tell
```

expected output is duplicating file to documents folder. But, when testing on certain Macs, the script shows an error ~10006. It works on other macs perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to copy the folder to a literal string (path) which can fail on machines running older system versions.

Remove the `as text` parameter to get an `alias` specifier

```
set destinationFolder to path to documents folder
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar error again: `Finder got an error: Can’t set alias "Macintosh HD:Users:sharedstudios:Documents:" to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:sharedstudios:Downloads:Portal Scripts:setup.app:Contents:Resources:Scripts:portal_resources".`

Comment: Try to move the line `set destinationFolder to...` to the beginning of the script outside of the Finder `tell` block. And the path to the source folder looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set folderToBeMoved to folder "portal_resources" of container of (path to me)
    set destinationFolder to path to documents folder
    set moveFolder to duplicate folderToBeMoved to destinationFolder with replacing
end tell
```

There were two issues here that I've changed. First, you convert things to text strings and try to modify the strings, but the Finder has a rich language for talking about file objects. You should just leave everything in object form. For instance, this:

```
folder "portal_resources" of container of (path to me)
```

tells the finder to find the folder of that name in that container and return an object specifier that you can use directly.

Second, once you have this object, you can't add the 'folder' specifier to it. Where you say:

```
duplicate folder folderToBeMoved
```

`folderToBeMoved` is already an object specifier (an object of the form 'folder [path]') so you're *actually* asking the Finder for 'folder folder [path],' which throws the error you're seeing. It's like saying to someone "pass the 'pass the salt.'" People are probably smart enough to figure that out; the Finder isn't.